# Node/JavaScript function to return a new path, given a filepath, basepath and new destpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, gulp, filepath

What custom function can be used (in node) whereby if passed three arguments, namely `filePath`, `basePath` and `destPath` it returns a new path. For example.

**Example function signature**

```js
var path = require('path'); // Nodes `path` module is likely to help?

/**
 * Returns a new filepath
 * @param {String} filePath - The path to the source file.
 * @param {String} basePath - The path to determine which part of the
 *     FilePath argument is to be appended to the destPath argument.
 * @param {String} destPath - The destination file path.
 * @return {String} The new filepath.
 */
function foo(filePath, basePath, destPath) {

    // ... ?

    return newFilePath;
}
```

**Example usage:**

Below are some examples of invoking the function and the value I'd expect returned given the arguments passed:

```js
// Example A

var a = foo('./foo/bar/baz/quux/filename.json', 'foo/bar/baz/', './dist');

console.log(a) // --> 'dist/baz/quux/filename.json' 

// Example B

var b = foo('./a/b/c/d/e/filename.png', './a/b/c', './images/logos/');

console.log(b) // --> 'images/logos/c/d/e/filename.png' 

// Example C

var c = foo('images/a/b/filename.png', './images/a/b', 'pictures/');

console.log(c) // --> 'pictures/b/filename.png'
```

**Further info**

1. As you can see from the example function invocations the `basePath` `String` will inform the function where the `filePath` value should be trimmed, and its purpose is akin to the *gulp* [base option](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase) used with the`gulp.src()` function.
2. The argument `String` values (i.e. paths) will always be relative, however, they will sometimes include the current directory prefix `./` and sometimes not. The trailing forward slash `/` may or may not be present on the path `String`.
3. The solution must work cross platform without any additional dependencies. It also must be usable with early node versions *( >= 0.10.28 )*
4. I've had various failed attempts using the utilities of the [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module, such `path.normalize` then splitting the `Array` etc, etc. However, I'm quite certain the [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module will be utilized in the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this using simple string replacement. Just normalize the paths before this.

1. filePath and basePath: if they start with `./`, remove it.
2. basePath : if it ends with `/` remove it, then remove the last path part (`baz` in your first example)
3. `filePath.replace(basePath, destPath)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function foo(filePath, basePath, destPath) {
    if(filePath.charAt(0)=='.'){
      filePath=filePath.substr(1,filePath.length);
    }
    if(filePath.charAt(0)=='/'){
      filePath=filePath.substr(1,filePath.length);
    }
    if(basePath.charAt(0)=='.'){
      basePath=basePath.substr(1,basePath.length);
    }
    if(basePath.charAt(0)=='/'){
      basePath=basePath.substr(1,basePath.length);
    }
    if(destPath.charAt(0)=='.'){
      destPath=destPath.substr(1,destPath.length);
    }
    if(destPath.charAt(0)=='/'){
      destPath=destPath.substr(1,destPath.length);
    }
    if(basePath.charAt(basePath.length-1)!='/'){
      basePath+="\/";
    }
    if(destPath.charAt(destPath.length-1)!='/'){
      destPath+="\/";
    }
    var temp = basePath.split('/')[basePath.split('/').length-2];
    var newFilePath = temp+'/'+filePath.split(basePath)[1];
    newFilePath=destPath+'/'+newFilePath;
    return newFilePath.replace(/\/\//g,"/");
}
// Example A

var a = foo('./foo/bar/baz/quux/filename.json', 'foo/bar/baz/', './dist');

console.log(a) // --> 'dist/baz/quux/filename.json' 

// Example B

var b = foo('./a/b/c/d/e/filename.png', './a/b/c', './images/logos/');

console.log(b) // --> 'images/logos/c/d/e/filename.png' 

// Example C

var c = foo('images/a/b/filename.png', './images/a/b', 'pictures/');

console.log(c) // --> 'pictures/b/filename.png'
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, however, examples B and C resulted in double forward slashed.  a = `./images/logos//b//d/e/filename.png` and 
c =  `pictures//a//filename.png`.

Comment: Which arguments would these be? Can you show me their function calls so I could reproduce (and hopefully fix) the error?

Comment: Apologies my previous comment says **a =** and it should say **b =** Simply invoke your function in node using examples B and C, (as defined in my OP), and you should see the double forward slashes in the resultant log.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying-- the filepaths given shoiuld be the results of running the examples they're paired to. Well, I fixed both the double-slash issue and an issue that happened if arguments 2 or 3 didn't have an ending slash.